# ORA-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month error when taking the sum or count

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

In my database I'm having a date column which is in varchar2 format when I tried to run the below query I'm getting ORA - 01847 error.

```
SELECT NVL(SUM(TOTAL_QOH),0) 
 FROM V_STOCK_ENQUIRY 
 WHERE LOCATION_ID = 82 
   AND TO_DATE(EXPIRY_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')>= TO_DATE('01-11-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
   AND TO_DATE(EXPIRY_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')<= TO_DATE('01-11-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

But when I try to run the same query but just take the TOTAL_QOH instead of the sum I'm getting it right. Could anyone help me resolve this please.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `select sum(nvl(TOTAL_QOH, 0))` ?

Comment: How is this related to both `mysql` and `sql-server`?` Know your DBMS.. Pick the correct one!

Comment: @Abra in theory at least, applying the `nvl()` once at the end is more efficient than doing for every row and adding up all of the zeroes.

Comment: My guess is you have an invalid value somewhere in your data, and your IDE (PL/SQL Developer etc) is pausing after the first screenful and therefore not hitting the error unless you apply an aggregate function which requires the database to process all the values.

Comment: The same error continues even with the above format

Comment: @ William Robertson If it is so then how is it working when I try to take the column directly

Comment: Is this a stand-alone query, or part of some PL/SQL code?

Comment: What is the data type of column `EXPIRY_DATE`?

Comment: What is the data type of `EXPIRY_DATE` if it is already a `date` - you should not use `to_date` use `trunc` instead. If it is a `varchar2` then I agree with @WilliamRobertson - check your data.

Comment: _If it is so then how is it working when I try to take the column directly?_ Typically IDEs like PL/SQL Developer, SQL Developer, TOAD etc don't display all of the rows from a query, but instead pause after the first screenful or some configurable number of rows. If your invalid value is in row 20000 you won't hit it unless you explicitly fetch at least 20000 rows, because SQL Developer or whatever you are using paused after 100 rows.

Comment: @ Abra  Is a stand-alone query

Comment: @ Wernfried Domscheit EXPIRY_DATE column is of type VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

Fetching part of rows may not cause errors, but when you sum then every row is checked and error occurs. Check your data, there should be wrong values somewhere, you could use below block code for instance. But the best option is to change column type to `date`. Storing dates as varchars causes problems like this and it's harder to build queries etc.

```
declare 
  dt date;
begin 
  for r in (select rowid, expiry_date from v_stock_enquiry) loop
    begin
      dt := to_date(r.expiry_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy');
    exception when others then
      if sqlcode in (-1839, -1847) then
        dbms_output.put_line('value: '||r.expiry_date||' is not correct');
        dbms_output.put_line('rowid: '||r.rowid);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
      else
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlcode);
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
      end if;
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: There are no wrong values in the data and I'm sure about this.